# How to properly set up a lives system for a side-scroller in pygame

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame

I have a game where the player has to dodge asteroids coming towards it, and I would like to incorporate a life system. Unfortunately, when I tried this, it still killed my player immediately. I printed out the player's lives as a test, and it is going from 3 to -7 whenever an asteroid hits it. How would I make it so that only one life is subtracted?

Here is my code:

```python
import pygame, random

from pygame.locals import (
    RLEACCEL,
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_SPACE,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("ship.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.lives = 3

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)

        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

class Asteroid(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Asteroid, self).__init__()

        self.surf = pygame.image.load("asteroid.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
            random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
            random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        
        self.speed = random.randint(5,20)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()

    def remove(self):
        self.kill()


SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 250)


player = Player()

enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            new_Asteroid = Asteroid()
            enemies.add(new_Asteroid)
            all_sprites.add(new_Asteroid)

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    enemies.update()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
            player.lives -= 1
            print(player.lives)
            if player.lives == 0:
                player.kill()
                running = False


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

UPDATE:
After trying out the first answer, here is the code for colliding:

```python
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies): # Check if collided
            if not new_Asteroid.collided_with_player: # Check if the asteroid has already collided with the Player
                # Substract a life, set the asteroids collided player to True so it does not substract more than one, and play some sfx
                player.lives -= 1
                new_Asteroid.collided_with_player = True
                move_sound.stop()
                hit_sound.play()

                # If there are no lives left
                if player.lives == 0:
                    heart1.kill()
                    player.kill()
                    running = False
```

(In the asteroid class I have the collided_with_player set to False by default)

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The player loses many lives because you don't tell your game to ignore collisions after the first frame there is a collision. Since there is a collision detected each frame, another life will be removed each frame until the collision no longer occurs (e.g. the Asteroid went through the Player).

I see two ways to fix it:

1. Once a collision with an Asteroid is detected, have the Player lose a life and *destroy* the Asteroid with a great boom! ()
2. If the Asteroid must not be destroyed because of the needs of your game design, add a flag `collided_with_player` on your Asteroid object (set to `False` by default), and once a collision with an Asteroid which has the `collided_with_player` set to `False` is detected, have the Player lose a life and set `collided_with_player` to `True`. This way you'll ignore future collisions between the player and this Asteroid.

Keep in mind that you have a flaw in your code. You're checking for collisions with *any* enemy, so you are unable to single out which enemy has hit the player (or rather, you're always affecting the last generated enemy). For this, you can change your code to *something* like this:

```
for enemy in enemies:
    screen.blit(enemy.surf, enemy.rect)

    if enemy collides with player and not enemy.collided_with_player:
        enemy.collided_with_player = True 
        player.lives -= 1
        print(player.lives)
        if player.lives == 0:
            player.kill()
            running = False

screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
```

Comment: I already had thought of 1. , but couldn't get it to work correctly. 2. I tried, and it almost worked, as it substracted the first life well, but when I hit asteroid 2, it substracted two lives at once. Here is the new collision:
            if not new_Asteroid.collided_with_player:
                player.lives -= 1
                print(player.lives)
                new_Asteroid.collided_with_player = True

                if player.lives == 0:
                    player.kill()
                    running = False

Comment: I also set the default state of .collide_with_player to False in the class.

Comment: UPDATE: Sometimes it substracts 2 lives, sometimes 1

Comment: @CodeWizard777 could you paste your whole updated code somewhere?